# Combining two array in python with np

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append

I have two array one with shape (320,1) and one with (850,1) how should I combine the two array. I tried np.append however it seems to be an error.

Comment: try np.concatenate((a, b), axis=0).[numpy concatenate](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)

Comment: What did you actually try?  What was the error?  What's the desire result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the two arrays are called arr1 and arr2, you could try the following code:

```
arr3 = np.append(arr1,arr2).reshape((-1,1))
```

The reshape is needed to make sure the final shape is (1170,1) instead of (1170,)